# Rendering timezone dependant datetime string without JS

Tags: html, html-email

I'm trying to send an html email that displays a datetime string comming from the server. The recepiant and server might be in different timezones, so I can't just format the datetime on the backend, also I CANNOT use js in emails due to security risks.

#### MY QUESTION

Is there any way to render a datetime string directly with html?

Currently I'm looking into something like this:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" value="2021-08-17T16:04:31.567394+00:00" disabled />
```

Comment: for email systems, the mail server handles the usual times of importance in regards to the mail itself.  for other times, consider attaching an internet calendaring and scheduling object (.ics)

Comment: Could you please provide the back-end programming language that you are using to send email?

Comment: I presume the datetime you want to show is for some sort of event... is there an "online" version of this event that the user could link to and see? e.g. if for the "Order date"... it could show the date as `August 17th, 2021 4:04pm (server time, UTC)` ... with a link to see the full details... which loads in the browser where you have more info and access to JavaScript etc.

Comment: @scunliffe yea, for now this seems like the way to go.. (explicitally stating server time) just to avoid confusion. These datetimes are intended for in house personel anyway, so it's not a big deal :)

Comment: Alternatively/additionally... if you have specific timezones that are key to your users... you could always calculate and render 2 or 3 specific values... `Aug 17th 12:04p (New York)`, `Aug 17th 09:04a (San Francisco)`, `Aug 18th 01:04a (Tokyo)`